# Need to update model from within AngularJS directive using touch screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I use ng-repeat to create a series of input fields on a form:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 input" data-ng-repeat="v in values">
    <div data-prefix-numeric-input data-prefix-name="{{ v.name }}">
        <input type="number" id="{{v.name}}" data-ng-model="form.numberArray[v.name]" data-number-validation />
    </div>
</div>
```

I use some css to hide the standard input:type=number spinners, using the following directive to create buttons more suitable for use on a touch screen device.

```
directives.directive('prefixNumericInput', ['$compile', function ($compile) {

    function getInputElement(attrs, element) {
        var inputTagType = attrs['cpNumericInput'].length ? attrs['cpNumericInput'] : 'input';
        return element.find(inputTagType);
    }

    function getInputValue(element) {
        var currentValue = element[0].valueAsNumber;
        return isNaN(currentValue) ? 0 : currentValue;
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'html-templates/numeric-input.html',
        replace: false,
        transclude: true,
        require: '^form',
        scope: {
            prefixName: '@'
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, formController, transcludeFn) {

            transcludeFn(function (clone) {
                var placeholder = element.find('placeholder');
                placeholder.replaceWith(clone);
            });

            var intervalId, inputElement = getInputElement(attrs, element);
            inputElement.addClass('form-control');

            // Add our buttons after the input's parent element
            $(inputElement[0].parentElement).after($compile('<div class="float-right">' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary inc-button" data-cp-touchstart="incrementStart()" data-cp-touchend="stop()" data-ng-click="increment()">+</button>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary inc-button" data-cp-touchstart="decrementStart()" data-cp-touchend="stop()" data-ng-click="decrement()">-</button>')(scope));

            function increment() {
                inputElement[0].value = 1 + getInputValue(inputElement);
                scope.$parent.$digest();
            }

            function decrement () {
                var currentValue = getInputValue(inputElement);
                inputElement[0].value = currentValue > 0 ? currentValue - 1 : 0;
            }

            scope.increment = increment;

            scope.decrement = decrement;

            scope.incrementStart = function () {
                increment();
                intervalId = setInterval(increment, 100);
            }

            scope.stop = function () {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }

            scope.decrementStart = function () {
                decrement();
                intervalId = setInterval(decrement, 100);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

The template is as follows:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">{{prefixName}}</span>
    <placeholder></placeholder>
</div>
```

This works well except for one issue. We only need one of the input fields to have a value. When the form is submitted another directive is run (cf. the number-validation above). This simply checks if any of the model values have something greater than zero entered. If so it validates the control in question. However if the user uses a touch screen and increments the value for one of the fields further down the page, every input field up to the field with the value is seen as invalid. This is because until it actually gets to the field with the value the model value doesn't appear to be set. I dumped the model array (form.numberArray) to the console in the validation directive and could see that each value was being appended each time the validation directive was run.

What I need is to have the model update when the button is touched. I tried using scope.$parent.$apply but simply got an 'in progress' error.

Any suggestions, guidance or recommendations gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I've come up with. Note that in the code I use 'prefix' as a placeholder for whatever prefix you may use to distinguish your logic from AngularJS's. I have a couple of directives to handle touch start and end:

```
directives.directive('prefixTouchstart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('touchstart', function (event) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.prefixTouchstart);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});

directives.directive('prefixTouchend', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('touchend', function (event) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.prefixTouchend);
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
```

I then use the following directive to create the input fields. Note that touching one of the buttons and holding your finger there will progressively increment/decrement the input field. The model is only updated though when the touch end event fires. The reason for this is while updating the model in the setInterval logic works, AngularJS doesn't reflect these changes in the UI, and we can't call $apply because we'll simply get 'in progress' errors ($apply is called in the touchstart/touchend directives. cf. above).

```
directives.directive('prefixNumericInput', ['$compile', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'html-templates/numeric-input.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            prefixName: '@',
            prefixModel: '=',
            prefixPlaceholder: '@'
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {

            var intervalId, inputElement = element.find('input');
            var currentValue = scope.prefixModel ? scope.prefixModel : 0;
            inputElement.addClass('form-control');

            // Add our buttons after the input's parent element
            $(element).after($compile('<div class="float-right">' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary inc-button" data-prefix-touchstart="incrementStart()" data-prefix-touchend="stop()" data-ng-click="increment()">+</button>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary inc-button" data-prefix-touchstart="decrementStart()" data-prefix-touchend="stop()" data-ng-click="decrement()">-</button>')(scope));

            function decrementCurrentValue() {
                if (currentValue > 0) {
                    --currentValue;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            function decrement() {
                if (decrementCurrentValue()) {
                    inputElement[0].value = currentValue;
                }
            }

            scope.increment = function() {
                scope.prefixModel = ++currentValue;
            };

            scope.decrement = function() {
                if (decrementCurrentValue()) {
                    scope.prefixModel = currentValue;
                }
            };

            scope.incrementStart = function () {
                inputElement[0].value = ++currentValue;
                intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                    inputElement[0].value = ++currentValue;
                }, 100);
            }

            scope.stop = function () {
                scope.prefixModel = currentValue;
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }

            scope.decrementStart = function () {
                decrement();
                intervalId = setInterval(decrement, 100);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

The following is the html template:

```
<div class="input-group column calc-width">
    <span class="input-group-addon">{{prefixName}}</span>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="{{prefixName}}" data-ng-model="prefixModel" placeholder="{{prefixPlaceholder}}" />
</div>
```

The code that creates the fields looks like the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 input" data-ng-repeat="value in values">
     <prefix-numeric-input data-prefix-name="{{ value.name }}" data-prefix-model="form.valueArray[value.name]" data-prefix-placeholder="Enter some sort of value here"></prefix-numeric-input>
</div>
```

We're using Bootstrap, hence the css classes littered throughout the logic. Hope this helps someone out.